# Uploading a file to Apache server with Qt

Tags: html, c++, apache, qt, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry pi running an Apache server. Inside a "pic" folder I have several png files, than I can display from any explorer using "http://192.168.0.23/pic.
I also can download all the files from my Qt (6.5) program using QNetworkAccessManager and request/reply system.
But I struggle to upload a file, I can check on server side, the file length is always 0.
Here is what I do :

```
    // Ouvrir le fichier PNG
QFile file(PICPATH_ABS + "TOTO.png");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier";
    return;
}

QUrl url(REMOTE_PIC_PATH + "TOTO.png");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

QHttpPart filePart;
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/png"));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"TOTO.png\""));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, file.size());
filePart.setBodyDevice(&file);

QHttpMultiPart multiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
multiPart.append(filePart);

// Envoyer la requête HTTP POST
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply * reply = manager.post(request, &multiPart);

// Connexion du signal uploadProgress() pour afficher la progression de l'envoi
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::uploadProgress, [&](qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal) {
    qDebug() << "Sent :" << bytesSent << "on" << bytesTotal;
});

QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec(); // Attendre la fin de la réponse

// Vérifier la réponse du serveur
if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    qDebug() << "Error : " << reply->errorString();
} else {
    qDebug() << "Success !";
}

// Nettoyer
file.close();
reply->deleteLater();
```

Here is the console output :

```
Sent: 16384 on 498328
Sent: 498328 on 498328
Sent: 0 on 0
Success !
```

I don't know if the problem comes from server side. I configured the folder "/var/www/html/pic" to be writable.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: How do you handle the file upload in the server? Do you use CGI, PHP or something else?

Comment: I have to admit, I do not know how to handle it on the server side. What should I do ?

Comment: Learn server-side programming or ask/hire someone. AFAIK Apache httpd doesn't handle file uploads for you. You have to write some code.